# php -> fwrite to process pipe hangs -> why?

Tags: php, pipe, fwrite

Can anyone say, why the following code hangs on `fwrite($pipes[0], $data);`, but it does not hang when I change `$bytesCount` to, for example, 1000?

I was not able to find answer via google :(
Thank you.

```
$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),
    1 => array("pipe", "w")
);

$bytesCount = 1000000;
$process = proc_open('cat', $descriptorspec, $pipes);
$data = str_repeat('a', $bytesCount);
fwrite($pipes[0], $data);
fclose($pipes[0]);
$response = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[1]);
$return_value = proc_close($process);
```

Comment: Does it work if you use `fwrite` with the third argument, then `fflush` the stream, repeat this a couple of times?

Comment: @AurelBílý no it does not)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipes are implemented with input and output buffers. `cat` starts to read, and copies everything to the output. When the output buffer is full, its write is blocked.

Since nothing is reading `cat`'s input (as that line is never reached), it will block indefinitely, blocking your `fwrite`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you.
If i read data from process stdout after each write to stdin - everying works as expected.